# Using the global URL variable as type

Tags: typescript

I want to return an `URL` object in order to use its `createObjectURL` function:

```
public static getGlobalUrl(): URL {
    return window.URL || (<any>window).webkitURL;
}
```

The definition of `URL` inside lib.d.ts does not contain `createObjectURL`. Instead it's defined like this:

```
interface URL {
    hash: string;
    host: string;
    hostname: string;
    href: string;
    readonly origin: string;
    password: string;
    pathname: string;
    port: string;
    protocol: string;
    search: string;
    username: string;
    toString(): string;
}

declare var URL: {
    prototype: URL;
    new(url: string, base?: string): URL;
    createObjectURL(object: any, options?: ObjectURLOptions): string;
    revokeObjectURL(url: string): void;
}
```

Is it possible to somehow use the declared variable as return type of my function or do I have to declare my own interface that extends `URL`? If so then why doesn't lib.ts contain such a derived interface?

**Edit to make it more clear**

```
export class Utils {
    // This is a DRY way to get URL:
    public static getGlobalUrl(): IUrlWithStatic {
        return window.URL || (<any>window).webkitURL;
    }
}

// lib.d.ts URL does not contain createObjectURL so lets make our own 
// interface: 
export interface IUrlWithStatic extends URL {
    createObjectURL(object: any, options?: ObjectURLOptions): string;
}

// Here I use my Utils for DRY reasons in a typed manner:
Utils.getGlobalUrl().createObjectURL(myBlob);
```

My question:

Do I always have to declare my own interfaces for this kind of functionality or is there some built-in way to use the static methods of something that is determined at runtime (URL vs. webkitURL) if there is already a declaration for it in form of a global variable.

Comment: All you want to do was to be able to call `createObjectURL` and for that you're trying to create an instance of `URL`? It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: @NitzanTomer I wanna do `MyClass.getGlobalUrl().createObjectURL(myString); `

Comment: `URL.createObjectURL` is static, see my answer for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `URL.createObjectURL` function is static, you don't need an instance of `URL` to use it, as it states [in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

> The URL.createObjectURL() **static method** creates a DOMString containing
>   an URL representing the object given in parameter.

So you can just do:

```
let url = URL.createObjectURL(myString);
```

It can also be seen in the definition that you posted.
The `interface URL` defines the members of a URL instance, while the `declare var URL` defines the static members, or the members of the `URL` class.

---

#### Edit

If you're asking how to have the `createObjectURL` available on the value returned from `getGlobalUrl()` then there's no way of doing it "natively".
In javascript static methods aren't available on instances.

You can however implement it yourself:

```
interface URL {
    createObjectURL(object: any, options?: ObjectURLOptions): string;
}

URL.prototype.createObjectURL = function (object: any, options?: ObjectURLOptions): string {
    return URL.createObjectURL(object, options);
}
```

---

#### 2nd Edit

You can do this:

```
public static getGlobalUrl(): typeof URL {
    return window.URL || (<any>window).webkitURL;
}
```

Comment: I'll take this answer as "It's not possible what you want out of the box ."

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're after. I thought that you want to be able to invoke `createObjectURL`. If that's not the case, then what do you want to do?

Comment: I re-read your question trying to understand what you're asking, and think that maybe I understand. Check my updated answer, hopefully I guessed right.

Comment: I also updated my question but you already understood what I meant :) I think I'll stick with my custom interface.

Comment: Ok, so I was a bit off with my guess. Check my 2nd edit of the answer, no need for the custom interface.

Comment: That's cool, does this feature have a name? It might be even more powerful if the return type was `typeof URL & URL`. I think this also should be correct.

Comment: No. If you return `URL` it means that you return an instance of it, but your function doesn't, it returns the class which is why it's `typeof URL`.

Comment: That means my sample with a custom interface is actually also wrong because the properties like `hash` are undefined, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above didn't work for me so I created my own type based on [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

```
export interface BrowserURL extends URL {
    createObjectURL(file: File | Blob | MediaSource)
}

const file = (window.URL as BrowserURL).createObjectURL(evt.target.files[0])
```